# Excel INDIRECT Function not working

Tags: excel-indirect

`C1` & `C2` changes dynamically.

Now, `C1` cell has - `T[IB_InteractType]={100,111,"111 MMT",180,8008000}`
 and `C2` cell has - `T[IB_OverallCSAT]={100,75,50,25,0}`

For checking purpose in cell `C3` my formula is giving right result. Where as the Indirect function in `C5` - `=SUMPRODUCT(INDIRECT(C1)*INDIRECT(C2))` is giving #REF! error.

In `C3` - `=SUMPRODUCT((T[IB_OverallCSAT]={100,75,50,25,0})*(T[IB_InteractType]={100,111,"111 MMT",180,8008000}))` gives the right count though.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

From the Excel help.  *Syntax INDIRECT(ref_text, [a1])  **ref_text:**
A reference to a cell that contains an A1-style reference, an R1C1-style reference, a name defined as a reference, or a reference to a cell as a text string. If ref_text is not a valid cell reference, INDIRECT returns the #REF! error value.*

Comment: do you mean indirect(c1) and indirect(c2) in my formula are invalid cell reference?

Comment: yes.  there values are not references, they are formulas

Answer (score 1):

The INDIRECT function needs to refer to a cell address as a string.  Try changing C1 and C2 to "C1" and "C2"